# How to update a grouped bar-chart in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/seG8eoRIKUD8Vs9Sva98?p=preview)** I've attempted to update the bars based on new csv data in a similar fashion to **[this](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b)**.

It fetches the new data and updates the rectangles but doesn't remove the previous data.

I have no idea what part of the code isn't working right, in a previous attempt I omitted `.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })` 
and got the leftmost group of bars to update and remove previous data but none of the other groups were showing.

Appreciate any help!

**EDIT:** Uploaded a working example **[here](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/d73ef3eb17287b30a87290cce57e2d98)**

Here's the relevant code:

```
let bars = g.selectAll(".test")
    .data(data)
bars = bars.enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { 
        return keys.map(function(key) { 
            return {key: key, value: d[key]}; 
        }); 
    })
bars = bars
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .merge(bars)

bars.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

bars.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers/groups in the chart do not seem to update as per the new data. Here's some changes you could make to the bars' enter, update and exit code:

```
var barGroups = g.selectAll("g.layer").data(data); 
barGroups.enter().append("g").classed('layer', true)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

barGroups.exit().remove(); 

var bars = g.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { 
        return keys.map(function(key) { 
            return {key: key, value: d[key]}; 
        }); 
    });
bars.enter().append("rect").attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

bars
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

bars.exit().remove();
```

So if you look at the code, bar groups/layers are being dealt with first and then the actual bars i.e. rectangles. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Awesome! Yes, please do that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Uploaded a [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/d73ef3eb17287b30a87290cce57e2d98)